# Skip row when writing to CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have written a script that collects data from 2 seperate API's and I am having trouble getting it to all show up on one row, instead it is showing up like this:

```
Device  Status  Model   StatusSub  

d8d     Online      
122  Disconnected
```

When I want it to look like this;

```
Device  Status  Model   StatusSub

d8d    Online    1202   Disconnected
```

Here is my code, the API is password protected so you will not be able to run it directly:

```
while True:#always run
if datetime.datetime.now().minute % 15 == 0 or True:#once every 15 minutes
    name = [('Device'), ('Status'), ('Model'), ('StatusSub')]
    space = [(''),('')]
    print (datetime.datetime.now())
    today = datetime.date.today().strftime('E.Subdevice.Logs.%m-%d-%Y')#file name
    if os.path.exists(today + '.csv'):#Create new file if its a new day
        Append_write = 'ab'
    else:
        Append_write = 'wb'

    with open(today + '.csv',Append_write) as myFile:#open todays csv file, set to write. 
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        writer.writerow(name)
        writer.writerow(space)
        #Loop to collect device name and status 500 at a time and print all 2080 in the file specified above.     
        for x in range(5):
            string1 = "https://api.raincloud.com/rest/device?networkName=Company&take=500&skip="+str(x*500)
            response = requests.get(string1,headers=headers).json()
            for y in range (len(response)):
                myData = [(response[y]['device']),(response[y]['status'])]
                string2= 'https://api.raincloud.com/rest/device/'+str(myData[0])+'/subdevice'
                response2 = requests.get(string2,headers=headers).json()
                for z in range (len(response2)):
                     myData2 = [(response2[z]['model']),(response2[z]['status']),datetime.datetime.now()]


                writer.writerow(myData)
                writer.writerow(myData2)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `writer.writerow(myData+myData2)` but `myData2` is assigned in a loop just above. That's clearly a code smell

Comment: also note that you can use append mode all the time: if file doesn't exist, it creates it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fix is pretty simple, just change

```
writer.writerow(myData)
writer.writerow(myData2)
```

to

```
writer.writerow(myData + myData2)
```

Every time you call the `writerow` function it will write to a new row. But if you want to write all your information to one row you need to perform it in a single `writerow` call. So combine your two lists into one list and call `writerow` on that single list

This bit of code though is slightly concerning

```
for z in range (len(response2)):
  myData2 = [(response2[z]['model']),(response2[z]['status']),datetime.datetime.now()]
```

This is looping over the array that is the json body of your second response, but it's overwriting `myData2` each time. So `myData2` is only ever going to equal the last model and status of your response.

You also don't have a timestamp column in your CSV but you are adding the time to `myData2` and writing it to your CSV.